# Sending Extra Message between Service and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, data-binding, service, broadcastreceiver

In my app I have TextField and button. When clicked, Service starts and reads value from TextField and triggers `AlarmManager`. After few seconds Service starts `BroadcastReceiver` and `BrodcastReceiver` start Second `Activity`.

`Activity` informs Service and sends value. I can see `Toast` with correct number in `Service`. But in Second `Activity` I see only the value that was entered for the first time.

For example: I wrote 5 and it's count to 5 and start BroadcatsReceiver and in Activity I can see 5. But if I will put right now 3, it will count to 3, but in secound activity show 5(example on the picture below). Next: I puts 8 it's count to eight, show correctly first Toast. In Secound activity still: 5. Even if I will upload program on phone one more time. Only way to see correct value is to delete application and starts it one more time. How can I fix it?

Method in MainActivity:

```
public void ClickStart(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        EditText numerField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numerField);
        String message = numerField.getText().toString();
        i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);
        this.startService(i);
    }
```

MyService:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        int countTime = 10;
        String data = (String) intent.getExtras().get("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
       countTime = Integer.parseInt(data);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyReciver.class);
        i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", data);
        Log.d("dddService", data);  // Correct data

        Toast tosty = Toast.makeText(this, data + " sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tosty.show();           

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 1, i, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (countTime * 1000), pintent);

    }
```

MyReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {


        String data = (String) arg1.getExtras().get("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
        Log.d("ddd", data);  //wrrong data
        Intent i = new Intent(arg0, MyActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(arg1.getExtras());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        arg0.startActivity(i);  
    }
```

My activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message + " Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
```

[image: Example. LogCat]

Comment: Are you trying to implement a counter, or? I suspect you are doing things more complicated than needed, so would like to know the goal of your code.

Comment: This is lab exercice. 
Create Activity A with an input field and a button
When the button is pressed Activity A should start a Service.
The Service sets an alarm using the AlarmManager. The alarm must be triggered after the amount of seconds specified in the input field in Activity A. When the alarm is triggered, a BroadcastReceiver must be notified.
When the BroadcastReceiver receives the notification, it must start Activity B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assuming you wish to move from activity A to B

1: in A register a BroadcastReceiver

```
// declare a field variable for the BroadcastReceiver
private BroadcastReceiver startActivityB;
// inside onCreate
startActivityB = new StartActivityB();
registerReceiver(startActivityB, new IntentFilter("INTENT_WAKEUP_B");

// inside onDestroy
unregisterReceiver(startActivityB);

// implementation of startActivityB as a private class inside A
private class StartActivityB extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        String data = (String) arg1.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
        Log.d("ddd", data); 
        Intent i = new Intent(arg0, MyActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(arg1.getExtras());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(i);  
    }
}
```

2: read the TextView value as you already do:

```
final String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

3: parse it to a numer, for example

```
int timeToWait = Integer.parseInt(message);
```

4: wait using a delayed handler and start activity B

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("INTENT_WAKEUP_B");
                            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }, timeToWait * 1000); // * 1000 if timeToWait is in seconds
```

5: in activity B fetch the message by overriding onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message + " Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: My mistake, in code I have parse: countTime = Integer.parseInt(data); in Service. I just missed to paste the code.  Counting works well. Problem is how to display value from text field in Secound Activity.

Comment: Answer now includes a broadcastreceiver

Comment: Okey, one more problem. In program I have to use AlarmManager not delay handler. When I used your way it works, but when I replaced it by AlarmManager - number are still not correct. But if i will add: sendBroadcast(i); message is correct, but Activity starts immeditly.